# Copy most recent file only from one blob to another using Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-data-factory

I am trying to copy the most recent file from the set of files with format "filename_yyyymmdd" from one container to another using ADF. I want a single file to be copied from those set of file.

How we can achive this ?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

1.create two variable and set value of `latestFile` as filename_19700101.
[image]

2.use `GetMetadata` activity to get child items.

3.use `ForEach` activity to loop child items and check Sequential option.Expression:

```
@activity('Get Metadata1').output.childItems
```

[image]

4.set value of `currentFile` as `@item().name`
[image]

5.use `If condition` activity to compare date by this expression:

```
@greater(split(variables('currentFile'),'_')[1],split(variables('latestFile'),'_')[1])
```

[image]

6. In True case, set latestFile value.
   [image]

7.Finally, pass `@variables('latestFile')` to file path in dataset within `Copy` activity
[image]

Comment: Hi Steve, Thanks for your response. I tried to implement this but copy data activity is aborting as @variable('latetsFile') is giving warning. How to use the value the variable in copy activity ?

Comment: @SHIVAMYADAV yes, it will give warning, but it  can work fine. You can try to run it.

Comment: Hi Steve, @greater(split(variables('currentFile'),'_')[1],split(variables('latestFile'),'_')[1]) will return array and i am getting " array index '1' is outside bounds (0, 0) of array" error

Comment: @SHIVAMYADAV you lose `_` character, please use this expression as step 5 shows `@greater(split(variables('currentFile'),'_')[1],split(variables('latestFile'),'_')[1])`.

Comment: @SHIVAMYADAV If you think my post helps you, you can mark it as answer. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hi Steve, I have modified the expression and used : @greater(substring(split(variables('currentfile'),'_')[1],0,8),substring(split(variables('latestfilename'),'_')[1],0,8)) . Its working fine now

Comment: @SHIVAMYADAV Congratulation for that! Could you please [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it as answer(click on the check mark beside my answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in)? Thanks. It may help others